# Hibernate,one-to-many, children not inserted with parent

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a bi-direction one-to-many relationship, ie one parent can have many children, one child must have one parent, many children can have the same parent.

See the following hibernate xml config. This works fine for loading the objects. Selecting a parent by its id successfully returns the parent object that includes a set of its children (if any).

However when I create a new parent, add some children and then ask hibernate to create the parent, the children aren't saved along with it. I would have thought hibernate would take care of that for me?

I suspect my issue is because the parent has a db managed sequence as an id so the children can't have their parent's id until after the parent is inserted. But then this shouldn't be too difficult for hibernate to handle should it?

Parent.hbm.xml;

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="none">
    <class name="com.mydomain.ParentImpl" table="PARENT" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="ID" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">PARENT_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        ....
        lots of other properties
        ...
        <set name="children" lazy="true" fetch="select" inverse="true">
            <key foreign-key="parent_child_fkc">
                <column name="PARENT_FK" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.mydomain.ChildImpl" not-found="exception"/>
        </set>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Child.hbm.xml;

```
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="none">
    <class name="com.mydomain.ChildImpl" table="CHILD" dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="ID" sql-type="INTEGER"/>
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">child_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="parent" class="com.mydomain.ParentImpl" foreign-key="parent_child_fkc" not-null="true" lazy="proxy" fetch="select">
            <column name="PARENT_FK" not-null="true" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
        </many-to-one>
        ...
        lots of other properties
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Assuming Parent class has a method;

```
public void addChild(Child child){
    if(children == null) {
        children = new HashSet<Child>();
    }
    children.add(child);
    child.setParent(this);
}
```

Then in code somewhere;

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.addChild(new Child());
parent.addChild(new Child());
getHibernateTemplate().save(parent);
```

Result is Parent is saved to PARENT table, CHILD table remains empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mapping and cascade to save children objects.

i.e.

```
<set name="children" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
<key column="parent_id"/>
<one-to-many class="Child"/>
```

See here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-update

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html

Comment: Thanks, I've made the change you suggested, basically the cascade="all-delete-orphan" is what I needed. However I'm now getting a PropertyValueException because Child.parent_fk is null when it comes to save the Child. This is because Parent.id only got set when IT got inserted and hibernate hasn't assigned it to the Child.parent_fk field?

Comment: Never mind, that Exception was because of code further down not properly setting the Child.Parent object relation when transforming from VO to domain objects.